# Python Web Scraping Error without Any Warning

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some text from a webpage and saving them in a text file using following code (I am opening links from a text file called links.txt):

```
import requests
import csv
import random
import string
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Create random string of specific length
def randStr(chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, N=10):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(N))
    
with open("links.txt", "r") as a_file:
  for line in a_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    endpoint = stripped_line
    response = requests.get(endpoint)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    for pictags in soup.find_all('col-md-2'):
        lastfilename = randStr()
        file = open(lastfilename + ".txt", "w")
        file.write(pictags.txt)
        file.close()
        print(stripped_line)
```

the webpage has following attribute:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
```

The problem is after running the code noting is happening and I am not receiving any error.

Comment: What are you trying to scrape from that page? Could you explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all keyword text from the page into a file, you can do:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.mykeyworder.com/keywords?tags=dog&exclude=&language=en"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

with open("data.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for inp in soup.select('input[type="checkbox"]'):
        print(inp["value"], file=f_out)
```

This creates `data.txt` with content:

```
dog
animal
canine
pet
cute
puppy
happy
young
adorable

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of BeautifulSoup [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find_all#find-all), you can see your line `for pictags in soup.find_all('col-md-2')` will search for any element with tag name 'col-md-2' not element with that class name. In other word, your code will search element like so `<col-md-2></col-md-2>`.

You fix your code and try again `or pictags in soup.find_all(class_='col-md-2')`

Comment: Thanks, I tried your recommendation and got this error "file.write(pictags.txt)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Tag". Sorry to bother you any suggestion is really appreciated

Comment: @KatherineElizabethKath : If you are trying to get text content from the retrieved HTML tag, you can try `file.write(pictags.text)`

Answer (score 0):

you can match the elements with relevant attributes.
pass a dictionary to the attrs parameter of find_all with the
desired attributes of the elements you’re looking for.

```
pictags = soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'col-md-2'})
```

this will find all elements with class 'col-md-2'